# Does the PHP password_hash salt include the trailing period?

Tags: php, hash, passwords, salt

According to this image: [PHP password_hash diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKtwp.png) from [the PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php#faq.password.storing-salts), the salt includes a trailing period, however as evidenced by previous information in "Algorithm Options" in which the trailing $ goes unused, this trailing period would go unused.

I'm more inclined towards it being unused but it's better to be safe than sorry.

Comment: There is no trailing period, it's just part of the character set the salt is made up of. You will get periods all over password_hash output, and the example in the docs might just be unlucky placement as it can make it seem like it's a divider between the salt and the hash. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f66c4edb9f7b4a3462a4dd22ee3a6add40c1ed95

Comment: @JimL I see, is the salt a fixed length? I seem to remember reading somewhere it's 22 chars long.

Comment: The salt is a fixed length. It's 128 bits. Which when packed in base64 becomes 21.33 characters. So the 22nd character is "shared" between the salt and the hash...